# Nodejs application monitor mongodb performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monitoring

I am using nodejs to running my application with mongodb host in composeio. 
I would like to have the tool can help me analysis the query performance executed by my application. For example query time execution, memory usage that consume of database, slowness query, count of query execution for each time frame.
Similar with Newrelic

Answer (score 0):

You can use any APM tool which supports Node.js for this. It really depends on what level of depth you need. The common ones would be AppDynamics, Dynatrace Ruxit, and New Relic. They actually do a lot more than your requirements but will help you diagnose issues.

Some of the tools such as AppDynamics can also monitor the MongoDB runtime as well. There are some specialist tools for node.js as well, such as Risingstack.